# How can I enlarge a div element from it's center when using 'position: fixed' ?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed size div element within a list of div tags (100% width, used on mobile website). Upon click, I want to make it full screen, so I add a class to it with the following properties: 
`height: 100vh; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;`.

The problem is that the css transformation starts from the origin of the fixed position (top left corner).

How can I make the transition effect from the fixed size to 100% w/h so that the css transformation will occur from the center of the element, pushing the other elements from the sideways (up/down)?

Without `position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;` the transformation occurs naturally (from the div's center), but it only pushes the following elements down and do not center the screen on the full screen div.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.  Please can you add the html and css you have already as you need to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: I've put it here: https://jsfiddle.net/k6cvtbzw/

Comment: I think you would need to do the animation with jquery rather than css

Comment: @TibiBuzdugan check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34156422/2733146)

Comment: @Pete do you know an example of jquery animation like this?

Comment: this is what I came up with - not perfect but could be a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/k6cvtbzw/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use css `zoom` property

> The zoom property in CSS allows you to scale your content

```js
var zoomFactor = 100;

function largeMe() {
  zoomFactor += 10;
  console.log(document.getElementById('center'));
  document.getElementById('center').style.zoom = zoomFactor + "%";
}

function smallMe() {
  zoomFactor -= 10;
  console.log(document.getElementById('center'));
  document.getElementById('center').style.zoom = zoomFactor + "%";
}
```

```css
#center {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #CCC;
  z-index: 200;
  margin: 5% auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<center id='center'>
  ...elements
</center>
<button type='button' onclick='largeMe()'>
  Zoom In
</button>

<button type='button' onclick='smallMe()'>
  Zoom Out
</button>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/kk7ctkx5/)

Comment: I tried this method, but it also scales the contents and it is not what I am looking for. I want to scale just the container so that it will fit the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

add these under .banner {}

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

and these under #banner.zoom {}

```
transform: translateX(0);
```

here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6cvtbzw/3/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but it's more like a hardcoded workaround. It works only in the demo case (i.e.: if the box is on the top of the page). As I want to use it in a list of elements, I can not use such an approach because it's original position on the screen is unkown. Maybe I can find it using jquery and edit the css accordingly..I shall try that

Comment: @TibiBuzdugan check the updated answer. You can use it with div's of any width/height.

Comment: @TibiBuzdugan making the outer div `position: relative` will help you to position them as well.